# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '<function calculateSlope at 0x1003c5bf8>'

Tags: python, string

I'm new to python, and I have an assignment due Friday. I use this code to find the midpoint, slope, and distance of 2 coordinates.

```
import math
def gcf(a,b):
    x = abs(a)
    while x > 1 and not(a%x == 0 and b%x == 0):
        x = x - 1
    return int(x)

def calculateSlope(firstX,firstY,secondX,secondY):
    Y = secondY-firstY
    X = secondX-firstX
    slope = Y/X
    return slope

def calculateDistance(firstX,firstY,secondX,secondY):    
    sq1 = ((firstX - secondX) * (firstX - secondX))
    sq2 = ((firstY - secondY) * (firstY - secondY))
    return math.sqrt(sq1 + sq2)

def calculateMidpoint(firstX,firstY,secondX,secondY):    
    midpoint = ((firstX+secondX)/2, (firstY+secondY)/2)
    return midpoint

x1 = float(input('Enter the x-value of point #1: '))
y1 = float(input('Enter the y-value of point #1: '))

x2 = float(input('Enter the x-value of point #2: '))    
y2 = float(input('Enter the y-value of point #2: '))

print('The slope is' + float(str(calculateSlope)) + '.')   
print('The distance is' + float(str(calculateDistance)) + '.')    
print('The midpoint is' + float(str(calculateMidpoint)) + '.')
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
Enter the x-value of point #1: 1
Enter the y-value of point #1: 2    
Enter the x-value of point #2: 3    
Enter the y-value of point #2: 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/muyeena/Desktop/Python 3.4/Adiat Muyeen Python Work/Functions with SlopesDistancesMidpoints.py", line 30, in <module>
    print('The slope is' + float(str(calculateSlope)) + '.')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '<function calculateSlope at 0x1003c5bf8>'
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just converting the function reference into `str` and then into `float` (which cannot be converted to float, since its not an actual float) , hence you are getting the issue.

Instead you should call the function with the values/parameters you took from user through `raw_input()` and convert that result to str. Example -

```
print('The slope is {0}.'.format(calculateSlope(x1,y1,x2,y2)))
print('The distance is {0}.'.format(calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2)))
print('The midpoint is {0}.'.format(calculateMidpoint(x1,y1,x2,y2)))
```